# Strange behavior when setting value types to null using reflection, why?

Tags: c#, reflection

look at the following example:

```
public class Test {
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public void TestReflection() {
        Number = 99;
        Type type = GetType();
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("Number");
        propertyInfo.SetValue(this, null, null);
    }
}
```

In the example I'm setting a `int` property to `null` using reflection. I was expecting this to throw an exception because `null` isn't a valid value for `int`. But it doesn't throw, it just sets the property to 0. Why!?

**Update**

Ok, it seems that is just how it is. The property gets the default value of the value-type if you try to set it to null. I have posted an answer describing how I solved my problem, maybe that will help someone someday. Thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sets the default value for the type. This behavior wasn't mentioned in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1.aspx) before, but now it is:

> If this PropertyInfo object is a value type and value is null, then
>   the property will be set to the default value for that type.

Answer (score 8):

It's probably setting values to the default for the type.  Bools probably go to false, too, I expect.

Same as using:

```
default(int);
```

I found some docs from MSDN the [default keyword in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of SetValue (or maybe the default binder) seems a little dangerous, Code equal to this solved my problem:

```
public class Test {
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public void SetNumberUsingReflection(object newValue) {
        Number = 99;
        Type type = GetType();
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("Number");
        if(propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsValueType && newValue == null) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Cannot set a property of type '{0}' to null.", propertyInfo.PropertyType));
        } else {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(this, newValue, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe it will help someone some day...